# perform unpivoting in a table by grouping 2 columns at once

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, unpivot

I want to perform unpivoting in following table to obtain output as described below.

INPUT

```
====================================
| ID | Subj1 | Mark1 | Subj2 |Mark2|
====================================
|1   | Eng12 | 24    | Mth23 |NULL |
====================================
|2   | PSY42 | 54    |NULL   | NULL|
====================================
```

OUTPUT

```
====================
| ID | Subj | Mark |
====================
|1   | Eng12 | 24  |
====================
|1   | MTh23 | NULL|
====================
|2   | PSY42 | 54  |
====================
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your data and expected output

```
SELECT
    id
    , subj1 subj
    , mark1 mark
FROM
    SomeTable
UNION ALL
SELECT
    id
    , subj2
    , mark2
FROM
    SomeTable
WHERE
    subj2 IS NOT NULL
;
```

Comment: Well that's one way to use it which i didn't notice. Though it is a bit slower than unpivot.